# Train an LSTM text generator against a function instead of data

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I have a model (G) that generates random molecules in their string representation such as COc1ccc2[C@@H]3.
However, these generated molecules are not guaranteed to be **valid** (chemically).

For this, I have a function that checks whether a given molecule is valid or not in the following form:

```
def check_validity(molecule_string):
    ...
    ...
    if valid:
        return 1
    else return 0
```

My question is, how can I train my model (G) against the check_validity function in an adversarial way in order to force it to generate valid molecules? which loss function is the most suitable and how to include it in a training loop?

Note: I am using Pytorch.

Comment: Such constraint optimization is quite hard in general and an open question. I don't have very good idea about your specific domain (molecules), but its unlikely that there is any standard way to do it. Most of the cases of constraint optimization require specific hand-engineered mechanisms depending on the nature of constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Training adversarially involves training a discriminator model (essentially a separate model from your generator model). You can directly train a model with input: string representation of molecule and output: classification as real or fake molecule. This would have to be trained with enough data to allow the model to infer the rules which make molecules valid/invalid.